# How to update a value within a mehod?

Tags: swift

I am new to Swift and I want to update the value with this line:

```
circleShape.strokeEnd = CGFloat(sum)
```

every time I click "calculate" (to get the value of sum). How can I do that?

This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var centerCircle: UIImageView!

var num1 = 0.0
var num2 = 0.0
var sum = 0.0
var a = 0.0
var b = 0.0

@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sumNum: UILabel!


@IBAction func vote1(sender: UIButton) {
    num1 = Double(label1.text!)!
    self.label1.text = String(num1 + 1)
    a = num1 + 1
}

@IBAction func vote2(sender: UIButton) {
    num2 = Double(label2.text!)!
    self.label2.text = String(num2 + 1)
    b = num2 + 1
}

@IBAction func calculate(sender: AnyObject) {


    sum = Double(a/(b+a))
    sumNum.numberOfLines = 0
    sumNum.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    sumNum.text = "\(sum)"

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // round view
    let roundView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(85, 100, 150, 150))
    roundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    roundView.layer.cornerRadius = roundView.frame.size.width / 2

    // bezier path
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint (x: roundView.frame.size.width / 2, y: roundView.frame.size.height / 2),
                                  radius: roundView.frame.size.width / 2.2 ,
                                  startAngle: CGFloat(-0.5 * M_PI),
                                  endAngle: CGFloat(1.5 * M_PI),
                                  clockwise: true)
    // circle shape
    let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()
    circleShape.path = circlePath.CGPath
    circleShape.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    circleShape.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    circleShape.lineWidth = 14
    // set start and end values
    circleShape.strokeStart = 0.0
    circleShape.strokeEnd = CGFloat(sum)

    // add sublayer
    roundView.layer.addSublayer(circleShape)
    // add subview
    self.view.addSubview(roundView)
    self.view.insertSubview(roundView, belowSubview: centerCircle)

}
```

Comment: can anyone help for this?...thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `circleShape` as a global variable and modify its `strokeEnd` value in the `calculate` function.

```
@IBOutlet weak var centerCircle: UIImageView!

var num1 = 0.0
var num2 = 0.0
var sum = 0.0
var a = 0.0
var b = 0.0
let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()

@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sumNum: UILabel!


@IBAction func vote1(sender: UIButton) {
    num1 = Double(label1.text!)!
    self.label1.text = String(num1 + 1)
    a = num1 + 1
}

@IBAction func vote2(sender: UIButton) {
    num2 = Double(label2.text!)!
    self.label2.text = String(num2 + 1)
    b = num2 + 1
}

@IBAction func calculate(sender: AnyObject) {
    sum = Double(a/(b+a))
    sumNum.numberOfLines = 0
    sumNum.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    sumNum.text = "\(sum)"
    circleShape.strokeEnd = CGFloat(sum)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // round view
    let roundView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(85, 100, 150, 150))
    roundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    roundView.layer.cornerRadius = roundView.frame.size.width / 2

    // bezier path
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint (x: roundView.frame.size.width / 2, y: roundView.frame.size.height / 2),
                                  radius: roundView.frame.size.width / 2.2 ,
                                  startAngle: CGFloat(-0.5 * M_PI),
                                  endAngle: CGFloat(1.5 * M_PI),
                                  clockwise: true)
    // circle shape
    circleShape.path = circlePath.CGPath
    circleShape.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    circleShape.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    circleShape.lineWidth = 14
    // set start and end values
    circleShape.strokeStart = 0.0
    circleShape.strokeEnd = CGFloat(sum)

    // add sublayer
    roundView.layer.addSublayer(circleShape)
    // add subview
    self.view.addSubview(roundView)
    self.view.insertSubview(roundView, belowSubview: centerCircle)
}
```

Comment: Really thanks! But seems that there still not working... it's suppose that after changing the value of strokeEnd(or the sum), there will be a change in colour of the circle's edge but it doesn't happen. Can you give it a help?

Comment: oh!!i found that i just make something wrong. It works!
Thanks man.